# How to get value for the next elements based on the first on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Code is

```
<div>
     <h5>
        <a class="site-name">KGC Alpc</a>
     </h5>
     <h5>
         <small class="site-address">1-221, Mandera st, CA</small>
     </h5>
     <input type="hidden" class="geocodes" value="11.5,33.4">
</div>

<div>
     <h5>
        <a class="site-name">ABC Transports</a>
     </h5>
     <h5>
        <small class="site-address">1-555, XX Street, NJ</small>
     </h5>
     <input type="hidden" class="geocodes" value="18.5,13.4">
</div>
```

If I click on the First element, I need to get the values of `Site Name`, `Site Address` and `Geo Code`

I tried like this

```
$('.site-name').click(function(event){
        var siteName = $(event.target).text(); 
        var siteAddress = $(event.target).text(); 
    });
```

From which I am getting my Site Name, but I am unable to get the Site Address and Geo Code values.

Please help me,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Using **parent()** and **next()** you can get the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.site-name').click(function(event){
        var siteName = $(this).text(); 
        var address = $(this).parent().next()
        var siteAddress= $(address).find(".site-address").text(); 
        var geoCode = $(address).next("input").val();
        console.log(siteName);
        console.log(siteAddress);
        console.log(geoCode);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
     <h5>
        <a class="site-name">KGC Alpc</a></h5>
        <h5><small class="site-address">1-221, Mandera st, CA</small></h5>
        <input type="hidden" class="geocodes" value="11.5,33.4">
     </h5>
</div>

<div>
     <h5>
        <a class="site-name">ABC Transports</a></h5>
        <h5><small class="site-address">1-555, XX Street, NJ</small></h5>
        <input type="hidden" class="geocodes" value="18.5,13.4">
     </h5>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try

```
$('h5.container').on('click', function(){
    return {
       siteName: $(this).find('.site-name').text(),
       siteAddress: $(this).find('.site-address').text(),
       geoCode: $(this).find('input').val()
    }
});
```

Add the class 'container' to your h5s just wrapping the 3 nodes.